# What to do when users outrun ajax

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

My program does an ajax call when the user clicks on a radio button.  Upon success, the background color of the table cell containing the radio button is changed to let the user know their selection has been posted to the database.

The problem is sometimes the background doesn't change. I'm trapping for errors, so I don't think it's because of an error.  I'm wondering if the user is outpacing the success callback.

```
var setup = {};
setup.url = 'Gateway.cfc';
setup.type= 'POST'
setup.dataType='json';
$.ajaxSetup(setup);

var settings = {};
settings.data = {};
settings.data.method = 'Save';
settings.data.AssignmentID = $('input[name=AssignmentID]').val();
settings.error = function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    $('#msgErr').text(thrownError);
};

settings.success = function(result) {
    $('#msg').empty();
    $('#msgErr').empty();
    if (result.RTN) { // uppercase RTN
        $('#' + settings.data.AnswerID).addClass('answer');
    } else {
        $('#' + settings.data.AnswerID).next().append('<span class="err"> ' + result.MSG + '</span>');
    }
}

$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
    var myName = $(this).attr('name');
    $('input[name=' + myName + ']').closest('td').removeClass('answer');
    settings.data.AnswerID = $(this).val();
    $.ajax(settings);
});
```

Comment: I think it may be a matter of you reusing the `settings` object as a global structure. You're resetting the ID in your `.change` function, but passing in the same settings object, so it's possible you could get a clash there. Have you tried duplicating the settings object and passing in a copy of the object to your `ajax()` call instead of reusing the global variable?

Comment: I think you mean: var obj = {}; $.extend(obj, settings); $.ajax(obj);

Comment: or better: var obj = $.extend(true,{},settings);$.ajax(obj);

Comment: Yep, does that help at all? That way you're not switching the data.AnswerID mid-request. And I would extend, add your AnswerID, and then pass that to the ajax() request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna post this as an answer, on the off-chance that it does the trick :)

```
$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').removeClass('answer');
    var mySettings = $.extend(true, {data:{AnswerID: $(this).val()}}, settings);
    $.ajax(mySettings);
});
```

This will make sure there are no race conditions with your settings if calls are made in quick succession.

Comment: I think this fixed it Dan.  Thanks!  I'm not sure I understand the data:{AnswerID: $(this).val()} part, so I just extended settings and it seems to work.

Comment: When you `extend` an object (in this case, `settings`), at the time you extend it, you can add additional parameters. So in your original code, you were setting `settings.data.AnswerID`. I simply extended settings, while at the same time, adding the AnswerID. Do it one line or two, you end up with the same thing. Glad that fixed your issue :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a delay between your Ajax post to the server and the ui element update on your screen. I do not know which Ajax library you are using, but you could plug into the Ajax framework and display a floating div element that covers the whole screen. This div could have other elements like an image or other divs, spans, p tags, etc. This is also called a dialog in some libraries.

I would recommend trying to find the before_Ajax_send and after_Ajax_receive functions in your Ajax library and attaching your functions to these events. The before_send function should display the floating div and the after_receive should close the div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're doing. You're preventing the user from clicking on another radio button until the ajax has finished.

Comment: I could turn async=false, but I don't think I want to cripple the user.

Comment: Yes, the point is to let the user know that your application is doing something, so please hold your horses. And I don't know what 'aync=false' does, but you probably don't want to do it, if it does what I think it does. You actually want the async functionality but just want the user to know that the application is doing something so please do not change anything on the screen as it could be overwritten. Also, your application's behavior could be really confusing if you do not use a modal dialog.